# How to add two bind params in knex?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm traying to select something from database and I have to use 2 bind params. With one param it works but with two i get this error "Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling RAW query" error and "Expected 1 bindings, saw 2" in nodejs console.

How to use 2nd bind param?

Code that works:

```
knex.with('with_alias', knex.raw('select * from "lyrics" where "for_id" = "1" and "var" = ?', var)).select('*').from('with_alias')
```

I also tried but it didn't worked

```
knex.with('with_alias', knex.raw('select * from "lyrics" where "for_id" = ? and "var" = ?', var1, var2)).select('*').from('with_alias')
```

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to pass two variables in an array:

```
knex.with('with_alias', knex.raw('select * from "lyrics" where "for_id" = ? and "var" = ?', [var1, var2])).select('*').from('with_alias')
```

It should work.