# How to rewrite raw sql query with knex?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, next.js, knex.js

I'm just new in development and it's the first time I'm using knex.

**Problem:**
I have a raw SQL query, which works properly. Now, I'm trying to use knex for this query. In order to learn how everything works I'd like to:

1. rewrite the query with knex.raw
2. rewrite the query using the knex query builder.

Could someone help me with that? Btw, I'm using Postgres and Next.js.
By running the code below I get "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expected 1 bindings, saw 0". I don't know if the problem is somewhere here:

> typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? [req.query.word] : req.query.word)

... so I already tried to rewrite it (used [ ]), but it didn't work. Here's the code:

```js
const getTranslation = (req, res) => {
  const params =
    typeof req.query.word === 'string'
      ? req.query.word
      : req.query.word.map((_, index) => `$${index + 1}`);
    console.log(req.query.word);

  knex.raw(
    `SELECT "Translation", "Words" FROM "Dictionary" WHERE "Words" IN (${
      typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? '($1)' : params.join(',')
    })`,
    typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? [req.query.word] : req.query.word)
    
      .then((error, result) => {
        const wordArray = typeof req.query.word === 'string' ? [req.query.word] : req.query.word;
        if (error) {
          throw error; 
        } 
        const wordOrder = req.query.word;
        result.rows.sort((row1, row2) => {
          return wordOrder.indexOf(row1.Words) - wordOrder.indexOf(row2.Words);
        });
        res.status(200).json(result.rows);
    }
  );
};
```

**What I've tried:**
I tried to use the following simple query to check if the configuration is working properly. And I think it does: the terminal (network) shows a request with status 200 and I see the data in the console...

```js
const getTranslation = (req, res) => {
  knex.select("Words", "Translation").from("Dictionary")
      .then(rows =>
        rows.map(row => {
          console.log(row)
        }))
}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```js
const results = await knex('Dictionary')
  .columns(['Translation', 'Words'])
  .whereIn('Words', req.query.word); // assumes that `req.query.word` is array with strings/numbers
```

Comment: Thx. I had to make small changes to .whereIn. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that I don´t actually know Knex.

But when I looked at some answers for the question in the link below, I noticed that they used "Knex.with()"

[How to add two bind params in knex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407751/how-to-add-two-bind-params-in-knex/54422388)

```
knex.with('with_alias', knex.raw('select * from "lyrics" where "for_id" = ? and "var" = ?', [var1, var2])).select('*').from('with_alias')
```

So it would appear that they are binding it together with "With_alias".

They also specified that you should try to passing variables in the array.

I hope this helps you alittle.

Comment: Thx for sharing the link. Yes, I tried to pass the values in an array (see my question), but it didn't work. I also assume that the error could be here somewhere. From what I understand, knex.with is used to give aliases - so, I don't think that this is the problem.